# Why is an ajax post with json content type sending data url encoded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Why is this call showing the values encoded onto the URL like so?

`http://localhost:49597/api/auth?user=jon&password=123`

Am using the following ajax call...

```
$.ajax({ url: "api/auth",
 type: "get", 
 data: { user: "jon", password: "123" },
 dataType: "json", 
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" 
});
```

I want the data to be sent as json...

Comment: You are using `GET`, you'll probably want to use `POST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is a **GET** request.

`GET` will send data in the querystring. If you want to avoid that, you can change your type to **POST** POST will send the data in the request body.

```
$.ajax({ url: "api/auth",
 type: "post", 
  //other stuff
});
```

If it is a Login form, you should probably use `POST` method.

Comment: In Chrome I get this in the payload: username=jon&password=123  Shouldn't it look more like json?

Comment: use `JSON.stringify` and then send the data

Answer (score 1):

`GET` requests do not have a request body, therefore all info must be stored in url as query parameters. I would also recommend not authenticating users with Javascript, and would definitely make that a `POST` request.

Comment: Why can't I send an ajax request with credentials? I need to post to server somehow...

Comment: Well first of all you are doing it over `http`, making it so that the users credentials can be seen by anybody.

Comment: When the project is finally deployed it will be on HTTPS.  Is this still a problem?

Comment: Well if your user has Javascript disabled its a problem :)  Whether or not that is a concern is up to you.

Comment: This is not 1990;) Surely we aren't still developing solutions for browsers in case javascript is turned off. In that case, most sites won't work.

Comment: @jaffa That would depend on what you are doing. If you are writing a web site for the government, 1-2% of your country's population may not be so small. Or if you web site gets 1 million hits a day, 10-20k is maybe a bunch of possible customers lost. Is it worth not having a non JS solution if needed, that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Because the code specifies a request of type `GET`.  A `GET` request passes the parameters via a query string.  You should switch to a post if you do not want to use a query string.

```
$.ajax({ url: "api/auth",
 type: "post", 
 data: { user: "jon", password: "123" },
 dataType: "json", 
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" 
});
```